# Gradle Multiproject best practice

Tags: eclipse, gradle

I have to following project / filesystem structure:

```
workspace (Eclipse folder for all my projects)
    Tools
    WebTools (depends on Tools)
    Project (depends on Tools)
    WebProject (depends on WebTools)
    more
```

Every Project is in git. I use Eclipse's build path -> Projects to include e.g. WebTools and Tools in WebProject. My favorite feature of this is that I can improve Tools / WebTools while working on any Project including the ability to refactor.

Currently I'm using Ant for distribution builds and include the sources of Tools and WebTools in the build of WebProject.

Now I want to migrate to gradle. The documentation suggests that subprojects always have to be in subfolders like this:

```
workspace
    WebProject
        WebTools
            Tools
    Project
        Tools (?)
```

But this interferes with my workflow because I need multiple copies of Tools/WebTools and eclipse can't refactor anymore.

Can this requirement (flat structure) be modeled with gradle? How? Or is there another workflow which allows me to work on multiple projects and dependencies which is recommended?

Comment: Logical project hierarchy != physical project layout. The latter is arbitrary, and can be configured in `settings.gradle`. For details, see `Settings` in the [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html). For a flat layout, simply use `includeFlat` instead of `include`.

Comment: Hey thanks! This is what I was looking for. Strange enough the gradle documentation in chapter 56 never mentions it.

Comment: See *55.3.2.2. Flat layouts* and *55.3.3. Modifying elements of the project tree*.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how big is the project and how many modules contains. There's no need to apply hierarchical structure as in maven - gradle can handle flat structures as well (and maven of course also). It seems that the project structure can be preserved and eclipse (or other IDE) should import it correctly. Refactoring among modules should also be working fine as far as the modules are grouped in under one parent - it looks like the modules are grouped here.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. The gradle documentation always uses subprojects in subfolders and I didn't find how to do it "my way". Do you know how gradle must be configured to work?

Comment: Use gradle wrapper - it does not require gradle to be installed - will download the distribution itself. Have a look here: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html 61.1 sample is what You need at the beginning. Multimodule project are configured in settings.gradle file. Refer to: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html

Comment: I don't see how gradlew helps here. I have gradle installed and it's working. The multi project documentation always talks about hirachical organisation of the directory structur. That is exactly my problem. I will clarify this in my question.

Comment: You asked 'Do you know how gradle must be configured to work?' - the answer is to use wrapper - no need for gradle configuration. Also wrapper defines version of gradle used with project - it simplifies import in IDEA for instance.

Comment: Sorry for my misleading question. This sentence is missing a "... in this way".